# Which tool to use to parse programming languages in Python?

Tags: python, parsing

Which Python tool can you recommend to parse programming languages? It should allow for a readable representation of the language grammar inside the source, and it should be able to scale to complicated languages (something with a grammar as complex as e.g. Python itself).

When I search, I mostly find pyparsing, which I will be evaluating, but of course I'm interested in other alternatives.

Edit: Bonus points if it comes with good error reporting and source code locations attached to syntax tree elements.

Comment: I think you will find the problem of defining the programming languages to be the hard part of your task. (If you want to parse Python, I'm sure you can get that off the shelf in Python). Parsing Java >=1.5 will be harder. Parsing C++ will be very difficult; wait till you get to C++11x. And you can't do much unless you do name and type resolution ("build symbol tables") after your parse. There's a lot more work here than you might guess. If your task is manipulating programming languages, you might consider a tool that can do this already, rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945357/python-how-best-to-parse-a-simple-grammar and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547782/mini-languages-in-python

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I really like [pyPEG](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/). Its error reporting isn't very friendly, but it can add source code locations to the AST.

pyPEG doesn't have a separate lexer, which would make parsing Python itself hard (I think CPython recognises indent and dedent in the lexer), but I've used pyPEG to build a parser for subset of C# with surprisingly little work.

An example adapted from [fdik.org/pyPEG/](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/): A simple language like this:

```
function fak(n) {
    if (n==0) { // 0! is 1 by definition
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * fak(n - 1);
    };
}
```

A pyPEG parser for that language:

```
def comment():          return [re.compile(r"//.*"),
                                re.compile("/\*.*?\*/", re.S)]
def literal():          return re.compile(r'\d*\.\d*|\d+|".*?"')
def symbol():           return re.compile(r"\w+")
def operator():         return re.compile(r"\+|\-|\*|\/|\=\=")
def operation():        return symbol, operator, [literal, functioncall]
def expression():       return [literal, operation, functioncall]
def expressionlist():   return expression, -1, (",", expression)
def returnstatement():  return keyword("return"), expression
def ifstatement():      return (keyword("if"), "(", expression, ")", block,
                                keyword("else"), block)
def statement():        return [ifstatement, returnstatement], ";"
def block():            return "{", -2, statement, "}"
def parameterlist():    return "(", symbol, -1, (",", symbol), ")"
def functioncall():     return symbol, "(", expressionlist, ")"
def function():         return keyword("function"), symbol, parameterlist, block
def simpleLanguage():   return function
```

Comment: Looks very nice. As I'll use Python in the initial design phase only, when performance is not a top requirement, this seems to be it.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to run this example. I assume it should be something like `from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function ;
from pypeg2 import * ; f = parse(example_string,simpleLanguage)`. Provided that you load the above example as example_string. But that doesn't work. Also, the syntax is very different from the (current )original example on the pyPEG website. Any suggestions how to run the same code?

Comment: @user989762 The link points at version 2 of pyPEG, which indeed uses a different syntax and conceptual model. Here is the version 1: http://fdik.org/pyPEG1/

Answer (score 19):

I would recommend that you check out my library: https://github.com/erezsh/lark

It can parse ALL context-free grammars, automatically builds an AST (with line & column numbers), and accepts the grammar in EBNF format, which is considered the standard.

It can easily parse a language like Python, and it can do so faster than any other parsing library written in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the well documented library. Only I couldn't find a Python parser, it said there is one in examples.

Comment: @serg I'm glad you like it! I refrained from adding the python grammars due to perfectionist reasons, but it's there now (in the [examples](https://github.com/erezsh/lark/tree/master/examples)).
If you want to do real work with the resulting AST, you'll still have to fine-tune it a bit (or wait until I do).

Comment: I love the library... Its just that the grammar reference doesn't give very many real-life examples... Still amazing library. :D

Answer (score 9):

[pyPEG](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/) (a tool I authored) has a tracing facility for error reporting.

Just set `pyPEG.print_trace = True` and pyPEG will give you a full trace of what's happening inside.

Comment: The tone of your answer is that of a conversation. Please use the comments section under the question to discuss the problem. Answers are answers to the post and should be informative, straightforward and not require response.

Comment: is there pyPEG2.print_trace = True ?

Answer (score 5):

Antlr is what you should look at http://www.antlr.org

Take a look at this http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3PythonTarget

Comment: Looks nice, but I have a personal hatred for anything Java. (Partly because it's an awful language to me, and because installations never worked correctly for me.)

Comment: Only the code generator tool is Java.  You can generate code for several languages, so you don't need to write or deploy any Java code to use ANTLR.

Comment: You need not know java to use antlr. Try it out they have a free book on the site as well. Once you are through chapter 4 you can simply use the antlr python parser grammer code from the website.

Comment: @Ankur Gupta, what free book?

Comment: @Stefan: Of all the software I've ever installed, the Java runtimes and development kits have given me the least (close to zero) trouble, and I've been doing this since Java first came out. (No, I'm not a Java lover, just a Java user).

Comment: The nice thing about antlr besides the IDE is the algorithm it uses for parsing is LL(k) which after taking compilers and using bison is quite refreshing and easy to use.

Comment: that link is broken

Comment: @AnkurGupta you can use ANTLRWorks IDE for generating lexers and grammers and testing them. Also can use antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3  MyGrammar.g4 command to generate python code for your lexer and grammer

Answer (score 5):

For a more complicated parser I would use pyparsing.
[Pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing)

Here is the parsed example from there home page

```py
from pyparsing import Word, alphas

greet = Word(alphas) + "," + Word(alphas) + "!"  # <-- grammar
```

defined here

```py
hello = "Hello, World!"
print(hello, "->", greet.parseString(hello))
```

Comment: The OP already knows about it and said he is going to evaluate it. Your point? (I am not the downvoter, BTW)

Comment: Pyparsing does belong in the answers, though, to allow up/down votes. It probably would have been better for the OP to include it as an answer right from the start.

Comment: I have been trying to use pyparsing and am finding it to be too restricting.

Answer (score 4):

Ned Batchelder did a survey of python parsing tools, which apparently he keeps updated (last updated July 2010):

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html

If I was going to need a parser today, I would either roll my own recursive descent parser, or possibly use [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) or [LEPL](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) -- depending on my needs and whether or not I was willing to introduce an external dependency. I wouldn't personally use PyParsing for anything very complicated.

Comment: This is bit of outdated comment, but just for the record, I would and have used pyparsing to implement something fairly complicated -- for maintainability, it's fantastic. Its one of the best pure-Python parsing tools in existence. I forget which famous programmer it was who said, "If you're thinking of rolling your own recursive descent parser, don't". Just my two cents.

Comment: `PLY` is the preferred solution after possibly prototyping with a lighter and higher level approach like `PyParsing`. The documentation of `PLY` is really good, error reporting is good, and it has a robust plain structure of defining the grammar. Even with `packrat` enabled, `PyParsing` can be orders of magnitude slower than `PLY`.

Answer (score 2):

For *simple* task I tend to use the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex#module-shlex) module.

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing for evaluation of language parsing in python.

Comment: shlex is not suitable for parsing complex languages like Python

Comment: @Sentinel, well aware of it,that's why I wrote *simple* :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're evaluating PyParsing, I think you should look at funcparserlib: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcparserlib

It's a bit similar, but in my experience resulting code is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Antlr generates LL(*) parsers. That can be good, but sometimes removing all left recursion can be cumbersome.

If you are LALR(1)-savvy, you can use [PyBison](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/pybison/). It has similar syntax to Yacc, if you know what it is. Plus, there are a lot of people out there that know how yacc works.