# Calling a function with unknown number of parameters Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to read in a Fuzzy plain text rule and pass the parameters to a SciKit-Fuzzy function call to create fuzzy rules.
For example, if I read in this text rule:

```
IF service IS poor OR food IS rancid THEN tip IS cheap
```

Then the function call will be:

```
ctrl.Rule(service ['poor'] | food ['rancid '], tip ['cheap'])
```

If text rule is:

```
IF service IS good THEN tip IS average;
```

Then the function call will be:

```
ctrl.Rule(service ['good '] , tip ['average'])
```

Since each rule can have unlimited number of input variables, e.g. the user can also say:

```
IF service IS good AND food IS good AND mood IS happy THEN tip IS high
```

which contains 3 inputs variables `service['good']`,`food['good']`,and `mood['happy']`, and 1 output variable `tip['high']`.
I can't think of a way to automatically read in the text rule and convert it to a function call, do you have any idea or suggestion to achieve this goal? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mini-languages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547782/mini-languages-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
string_input = "IF service IS poor OR food IS rancid THEN tip IS cheap"
string_input = string_input.replace(" THEN ", '"], ').replace(' IS ', '["').strip("IF ").replace(" OR ", '"] | ') +'"]'
eval('ctrl.Rule({})'.format(string_input))
```

But be warned you need to be very very careful with eval. It is a security risk because user can execute code this way!!! Before using this you might to do research on how to prevent this security issue.

Comment: This `eval()` function can solve my problem perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help, but as mentioned be aware of potential safety issues if you are considering that user will write that input! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 4):

In python, we can pass an unknown amount of arguments into the function using asterisk notation.

Let's try to create a function `sum_up()` with an unknown number of arguments.

```py
def sum_up(*args):
    s = 0
    for i in args:
        s += i
    return s
```

As you see, an argument with an asterisk before will collect all arguments given to this function inside a tuple called `args`.

We can call this function that way:

```py
sum_up(5, 4, 6)  # Gives 15
```

But if we want to sum up elements of a list and we need to pass it into the function as arguments...

We can try the following:

```py
l = [5, 4, 6]
sum_up(l)
```

This won't give an effect we need: `args` of `sum_up` will look like `([5, 4, 6],)`.
To do what we want, we need to put an asterisk before the argument we're passing:

```py
sum_up(*l)  # Becomes sum_up(5, 4, 6)
```

All you need to do is collect all arguments you want to pass in a list and then put an asterisk before this list passed as an argument inside a call:

```py
args = [service ['good '] , tip ['average']]
ctrl.Rule(*args)
```